# Unnecessary Latency buckets getting created using Micrometer For Spring-boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, monitoring, micrometer, spring-micrometer

Defined latency buckets for `http.server.requests` metric using below config for spring-boot application
:

```
management.metrics.distribution.slo.http.server.requests=1ms,5ms,15ms,50ms
```

But it's creating intermediate buckets also. Can anyone help me explain how we can configure it properly so that intermediate buckets won't be created.

Example :
Between 1ms to 5ms below are buckets getting created.

```
le="0.001",} 425928.0
le="0.001048576",} 425933.0
le="0.001398101",} 425971.0
le="0.001747626",} 426015.0
le="0.002097151",} 426019.0
le="0.002446676",} 426022.0
le="0.002796201",} 426028.0
le="0.003145726",} 426029.0
le="0.003495251",} 426030.0
le="0.003844776",} 426030.0
le="0.004194304",} 426030
le="0.005",} 426030
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you also enabled percentile histograms (asked for those buckets) either from Java config or using this property:

```
management.metrics.distribution.percentiles-histogram.http.server.requests=true
```

or

```
management.metrics.distribution.percentiles-histogram.all=true
```